# How can I check the data of a form using javascript and then redirected to a second html file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, electron-builder

I make a login screen using electron and node.js. What I am trying to do is that the user puts the correct data in the form and after pressing the button submit all the data that he put will be checked and If the user put the correct one he will be directed to a second .html file called second.html. I tried this but without any result.

This is the js code:

```
const electron= require('electron');
const {app, BrowserWindow}=electron;
let loginWindow;
let mainWindow;
app.on('ready',()=>{
loginWindow=new BrowserWindow({});
loginWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`);
});
```

And this is the index.html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta chaset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href ="css1.css">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="center">
  
  <form metod="post">
      <div class="txt_field">
          <input id="username" type="text" required>

          <label>Username</label>
      </div>
      <div class="txt_field">
          <input id="password" type="password" required>

          <label>Password</label>
      </div>
      <div class="pass">Forgot Password?</div>
      <input onclick="press" type="submit" id="submit" value="Login">
      <div class="signup_link">
        Not a member?<a href="#">Sing up </a>
      </div>
  </form>
</div>
</body>
<script src="main.js">
  require('./renderer.js');
  function press(){
    var username=document.getElementById("username");
    var password=document.getElementById("password");
    if(username==1 && password==1)
    window.open('second.html');
  }
</script>
```

As you can see I tried to do this by my self but it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you're comparing two inputs with each other, which both are object. What you'll need to do is to get the `value` property of each input and compare those values.

```
function press(){
  var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
  var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
  
  if (username == 1 && password == 1) {
    window.open('second.html');
  }
}
```

### Disclaimer: Let the backend handle logins

**The frontend is very insecure when it comes to logins. You say you've got a Node.js server. Send the form to an endpoint, check the values and then redirect the user. Anything on the frontend can be read by the user and is therefor insecure.**

That being said;

The form will still submit and reload the page. What you should do is listen for the `submit` event. That event is triggered whenever the submit button is clicked. When that event fires, prevent the form from submitting and call your function which evaluates the values. See the example below.

```html
<form id="login-form" method="post">
  <div class="txt_field">
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input id="username" type="text" required>
  </div>

  <div class="txt_field">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input id="password" type="password" required>
  </div>
  
  <div class="pass">Forgot Password?</div>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Login">
    <div class="signup_link">
      Not a member? <a href="#">Sign up</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

```
const loginForm = document.getElementById('login-form');

loginForm.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  press(); // Evaluate the values.
  event.preventDefault(); // Prevent form from submitting.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use field name to fetch the value on submission.

```
      <div class="txt_field">
          <input id="username" name="username" type="text" required>
          <label>Username</label>
      </div>
      <div class="txt_field">
          <input id="password" name="password" type="password" required>
          <label>Password</label>
      </div>


document.getElementById("login-form").elements["username"].value
document.getElementById("login-form").elements["password"].value
```

It is recommended that you use field name instead of Id because its the field name and value that is sent as a form data in the post request.